# Creating users on OSX 10.5 and up from the command line

Tags: mac-osx, user-management, terminal

Is this even possible anymore? I've seen tutorials which use niutil (not available on my Mac) and dscl.

My output from dscl is the following though, kind of odd:

```
neutron:~ username$ sudo dscl / -create /Users/deadline
Data source (/) is not valid.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` isn't a valid node name (think network host names); for the local host's default store you can use `.`, or use `localhost` to specify the store.

```
$ sudo dscl . -create /Users/deadline                       # the common way
$ sudo dscl localhost -create /Local/Default/Users/deadline # same thing
```

Comment: Good call. I thought I'd tried local host at one point, but apparently I hadn't.